# Asus M32CD-B09 cannot install

Tags: uefi, asus, bios

I recently bought an Asus M32CD-B09 Desktop.  I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.  I've turned off all UEFI secure boot stuff in my BIOS.  When I try to install, it gets past the page asking if I would like to install updates.  Then I get an error saying something like, an error occurred, would you like to retry or cancel or continue.  I select continue.  It starts installing but locks up.  I am able to restart the PC and boot back into Windows which tells me it can't even write to my hard drive.  It's like secure boot or some kind of boot loader lock is enabled and ubuntu can't touch my hard drive.  But I turned off all secre boot and deleted all the secure boot keys.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Also, I changed my boot order from uefi CDROM and HD to just CDROM and HD.

Comment: " I've turned off all UEFI secure boot stuff in my BIOS"... how many things did you change? Secure boot is only one setting. Did you change UEFI to legacy/BIOS? Change all the settings back. Report back.

Comment: Ok, the error I receive when trying to install Ubuntu is 

ubi-partman crashed

ubi-partman failed with exit code 10.  Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: You didn't say what BIOS settings you changed. The "changed my boot order from uefi CDROM and HD to just CDROM and HD" at least, should be set back.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Had to add these two lines to grub boot loader during install...

i915.preliminary_hw_support=1

pci=nomsi

Also had to make sure all secure boot keys were deleted in the bios and none of the boot drives were set to uefi.